# Error Displaying Windows using Boost Thread & OpenCV OSX

Tags: multithreading, macos, boost, opencv, homebrew

So I am aware of the following link: [Problem accessing camera when using Boost thread on OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5199257/problem-accessing-camera-when-using-boost-thread-on-osx)

But my issue is that I cannot display windows when using openCV from within a boost thread. I.e:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    CvCapture* cvInputObj = cvCaptureFromCAM((CV_CAP_ANY)); //OSX
    assert( cvInputObj != NULL ); //term on fail here
    cVision vision(cvInputObj); //Define cVision thread obj
    boost::thread cVision_thd(boost::bind(&cVision::Run, &vision));
    cVision_thd.join();
    std::cout<<"System Going Down..."<<std::endl;
}
```

In cVision I do a bunch of openCv calls such as for ex:

```
            cvNamedWindow("MONITOR", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
        cvShowImage("MONITOR", imCur);
```

etcetc, where imCur is extracted out as such:

```
        imCur = cvQueryFrame(input);
```

This exact code works perfectly in Linux. I have originally tried this with a custom makefile. That did not work. After this I tried with CMAKE. Still the same result. And still works fine in linux. I installed openCV using homebrew.

Answer (score 0):

Create the window in the `main` thread, and then pass the name of the window as a parameter to `cVision` constructor.

Remember, the window is created with: `cvNamedWindow("MONITOR", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);`

Comment: Thanks, I tried this. All I need is the string value for the name right? So basically I am doing a simple cvShowImage("MONITOR", imCur). I see the first frame or two update, but then nothing. The first image captured seems to be a higher res (as observable by the larger window size) and then it crops it down to 640x480. Problem is I set the image size via cvSetCaptureProperty right before the cvShowImage

Comment: In essence the following happens: Main creates CvCapture object and window and passes it to the cVision thread. This thread has the following & i see the "Test" being printed repeatedly, however the input image does not update:      cvShowImage("ISIS_MONITOR", imCur);
   std::cout<<"Test\n";