# OpenCV VideoCapture does not block on OS X

Tags: multithreading, macos, opencv, camera, capture

Short version: on OS X, if I call VideoCapture::read() from a thread other than the main() thread, the call returns immediately instead of blocking till a new frame.

This one works as expect:

```
void main()
{
    VideoCapture vc(0);

    Mat img;
    While(1) {
        vc.read( img ); // blocks till new frame arrives
    }    
}
```

This one does not block:

```
void run( VideoCapture& vc )
{
    Mat img;
    While(1) {
        vc.read( img ); // returns immediately and always returns true
    }    
}

void main()
{
    VideoCapture vc(0);
    boost::thread capThread( boost::bind( &run, vc ) );
    capThread.join();
}
```

So in the second version with a separate thread to grab frames, the call to VideoCapture::read(img) returns immediately with return value true, and img is set to the current frame, which means it'll return many duplicate frames.

It's mentioned here:

[Problem accessing camera when using Boost thread on OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5199257/problem-accessing-camera-when-using-boost-thread-on-osx)

that:

"The OpenCV Camera functions on mac require access to an objective-c NSRunLoop; don't know how to get at one from a new thread though."

Anyone know of a solution to do a blocking frame grab from a thread other than the main() thread?
Alternatively, is there a nice way to discard the duplicate frames?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**OpenCV doesn't support multi-threading.**

Let the main thread capture the frames and do whatever you need to do in the second thread.

Comment: What if i NEED it to not block, but would like to use polling instead of threads? Is that possible?