# Unable to start camera capture in Python-OpenCV (cv2) using a non-main thread

Tags: python, opencv

I have some python-opencv (cv2) code that opens the video capture device (camera):

```
self.capture = cv2.VideoCapture(device)
```

If I call this code from the python main thread, the VideoCapture starts OK; however, if I call this setup code from a non-main thread, the camera never opens. The VideoCapture() call never returns.  I'm creating a background thread by simply doing:

```
run_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.run)
run_thread.start()
```

Is this simply a bug in OpenCV/cv2 or am I overlooking a limitation of python threads?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16683178/777285) mentions quite summarily that it's an `openCV` limitation. Also, this constraint exists for the `show` and `waitKey` methods.

This [official code sample](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/samples/python/video_threaded.py) can give some ideas on python-openCV multithreading.

Comment: That other SO post appears to be obsolete or incorrect, at least for t OpenCV 2.4.6 running on OSX, in that I can capture frames in a background thread, I just can't start the VideoCapture in anything but the main thread.   Anyhow, thanks for the link.

Comment: Official code sample is now here: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/samples/python/video_threaded.py